# vb.net Aspose.OCR - Extract text from Image

Tags: vb.net, winforms, bitmap, aspose

i tried to extract text from image by `Aspose.OCR`,

my code:

```
Const resourceFileName As String = "c:\2011.08.05 v1.1 Aspose.OCR.Resouces.zip"
        Dim uploadedImage As String = "c:\ConvertMeToText.bmp"
        Try
            'Create OcrEngine instance and assign 
            'image, language and image configuration
            Dim ocr As New OcrEngine()
            ocr.Image = ImageStream.FromFile(uploadedImage)

            ocr.Languages.AddLanguage(Language.Load("english"))
            ocr.Config.NeedRotationCorrection = True
            ocr.Config.UseDefaultDictionaries = True
            Dim fileStream As New FileStream(resourceFileName, FileMode.Open)
            ocr.Resource = fileStream
            Try
                If ocr.Process() Then
                    TextBox1.Text = ocr.Text.ToString()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Exception: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
            fileStream.Close()
            ocr = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox("Exception: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Exception:
     ZipEntry::ReadHeader(): Bad signature (0x00000100) at position  0x00000000

Answer (score 1):

my name is Nayyer and I work as a support developer / Technical Evangelist at Aspose.

From exception, it looks like there is some difference in Aspose.OCR version and resource file version. Every Aspose.OCR release uses a separate resources.zip file and if you try to use Aspose.OCR v1.0.0 with 2011.08.05 v1.1 Aspose.OCR.Resouces.zip then you might get similar exception. May be you can try the latest version of [Aspose.OCR v.1.1.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.ocr_for_.net/entry324278.aspx) and its compatible resource file is available over [this link](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.ocr_for_.net/entry323723.aspx).